# регулярное выражение @username123_-

Tags: регулярные-выражения

здравствуйте, как с помощью регулярки выявить из любого текста

> "@user1-_"

тоесть собака @ затем любые буквы и цифры так же (необязательно) "_" или "-"

Comment: Вот что ловит выбранный ответ https://regex101.com/r/48Ypl8/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну как-то так:

```
/\@[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+/
```

Демо: [regex101.com/r/SOG3LN/3](https://regex101.com/r/SOG3LN/3)

Это же минимальные знания регулярных выражений.

Answer (score 0):

Или так:

```
(?:(?<=^|[^\w0-9-_])(?<!@)@)([\w0-9-_]*)(?=[^\w@]|$)(?!@)
```

[Демо](https://regex101.com/r/L7PEd0/1)